# magento language switcher not showing

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

all

I installed a magento theme for a friend pagayo electronics and for some reason the language switcher dissapear as soon we changed the template.

Do you have any idea?>

Inside the new template file / magento / app / design / frontend / default / pagayo-theme-001 / template / page / html / header.phtml the following exists for language picker:

```
<div class="header-right">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>


        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>


    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_switcher') ?>

    <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('accountLinks') ?></p>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
            <div class="welcome-msg">
                <?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>
```

and also in the file / magento / app / design / frontend / default / pagayo-theme-001 / layout / page.xml the following exists for language

```
  <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Header</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
```

if you have any idea it would be great. bare in mind magento version is 1.9.2.1 and the theme i installed is :
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/free-theme-electronics-online-by-pagayo.html

also if i view the generated code in the front end from the browser there is not code regarding language switch. If i return back to the default theme the code and the language switcher is there.

Comment: "Not showing" as in, it's not visible, or the code for the language switcher is not there at all? did you try and inspect the code from your browser?

Comment: yes the code in the browser in not there at all. If i switch back to the default template of magento the switcher is there.

Comment: @Qaisar i am talking about the language not the currency my friend